# Why did my in app purchase break when I changed my binary name?

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect

I recently changed the binary name for my app.  Now my StoreKit request returns an invalid product identifier for my in app purchase.  I did not change my product identifier, or my app bundle id.

Game Kit still seems to be working fine.  The only thing I did was rename my binary...  Can anyone suggest why this might have broken my in app purchases?

Edit:  Game Kit is also apparently not working.  I can view my leaderboards and whatnot, but it says Game not recognized by Game Center when I log in.

Comment: How did you change the binary name for your app?

Comment: I changed the name of the xcode project from within xcode, which in turn changes the name of the target etc.  I seem to have fixed things now, just testing some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK at the risk of looking like a moron, I'll post what apparently fixed my issue.

I simply deleted the app off my phone manually (by holding down on the icon and hitting the x when it pops up)

I'd tried cleaning and re-building etc. so I figured that was enough, but the manual delete seemed to work.  I should also mention that I changed my xcode project name back to the original.

To anyone else who changes their project name and experiences issues with in app purchase or game center stuff, delete your app off of your phone and re-install it!

I'm not sure if changing the name back made a difference or not.

Also, if you're just looking to change the display name of your app, there's a field in info.plist for that.